# Unable to append items with jquery masonry in wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, pagination, append, jquery-masonry

I know there are a lot of questions about masonry here, but I couldn't seem to find the answer to what might be an obvious fix. I'm trying to get the append method to work: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html, but where do those Append and Prepend buttons come from? The code doesn't seem to mention how to connect these buttons with the script. I'd like to add a load more button to append the next set of wordpress posts, just can't seem to find the solution anywhere. If anyone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var $container = $('#linky');
var $boxes = $('<div class="boxy"/><div class="boxy"/><div class="boxy"/>');

$container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.boxy',
    isFitWidth: true,
    singleMode: true,
    isAnimated: false,   

     }); 
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View the source for that demo page.  If you look towards the very bottom there is a section of code that runs when those buttons are clicked.  They are what trigger the function call.

```
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.box',
      columnWidth: 100,
      isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
    });

    $('#prepend').click(function(){
      var $boxes = $( boxMaker.makeBoxes() );
      $container.prepend( $boxes ).masonry( 'reload' );
    });

    $('#append').click(function(){
      var $boxes = $( boxMaker.makeBoxes() );
      $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );
    });

  });
</script>
```

the `$('#prepend').click(...` says that, on click of the element with ID "prepend", run the following function.  If you look at the buttons they have on the page, they are simple buttons with IDs that match the functionality in this part (ids prepend and append.)

```
<button id="prepend">Prepend new items</button>
<button id="append">Append new items</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Walls. That was the missing piece I needed. Now I just need to learn how to customize the box-maker javascript to pull in my posts instead of their random lorem ipsum. Thanks again.